# jquery plugin lava lamp not working in IE6

Tags: jquery, browser

Am using jquery plugin Lava lamp that is not working in IE6 .....particularly at the mouse hover event.but it's working in firefox.

Here is my code

```
css file of lava lamp plugin

        .lavaLampWithImage {
            position: relative;
            height: 70px;
            width: 900px;
            /*background: url("bg.gif") no-repeat top;*/
            background: url("../../../images/bgheader.jpg") repeat top;

            padding: 1px;
            margin: 1px 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
                .lavaLampWithImage li {
                    float: left;
                    list-style: none;
                }
                    .lavaLampWithImage li.back {
                        /*background: url("lava.gif") no-repeat right -30px; 
                         background: url("../../../images/newsbarbg.jpg") repeat right -30px;*/
                        width: 1px; height: 30px;
                        z-index: 8;
                     position: absolute;

                    }
                        .lavaLampWithImage li.back .left {
                            background: url("lava.gif") no-repeat top left;
                            /* background: url("../../../images/newsbarbg.jpg") repeat top left;*/
                            height: 21px;
                            margin-right: 9px; /* 7px is the width of the rounded shape */
                        }
                    .lavaLampWithImage li a {
                        font: bold 11px arial;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        color: #fff;
                        outline: none;
                        text-align: center;
                        top: 7px;
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                        letter-spacing: 0;
                        z-index: 10;
                        display: block;
                        float: left;
                        height: 21px;
                        position: relative;
                        overflow: hidden;
                        margin: auto 8px;    
                    }
                        .lavaLampWithImage li a:hover, .lavaLampWithImage li a:active, .lavaLampWithImage li a:visited {
                            border: none;
                        }
```

And that is my jquery code for lava lamp plugin

```
$(function() {
            $("#1").lavaLamp({
                fx: "backout",
                /*speed: 700,*/
                speed: 700,
                //returnDelay:1000,

                click: function(event, menuItem) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is within this function

click: function(event, menuItem) {
                    return false;
                }

basically if you click a link the javascript will return false, as if saying "stop", you can delete these last lines or simply comment out the return false line

click: function(event, menuItem) {
                    //return false;
                }

this way you don't need to worry about what to return and even the dumbest and oldest browsers will follow a link, even IE6 lol